# Widget that add or subtract one day from each date of a column in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, date, kendo-grid

I would like to create a widget for each column of my kendo grid that can add or subtract one day from each date of that specific column. These are the columns

```
initGridReparti: function initGridReparti() {

    var gridColumns = [
    {
        field: "repartoDescr",
        title: "Reparto",
        width: 200
    },

    { 
        field: "dataAtt", 
        title: "Data Attivazione",
        format:"{0:dddd dd MMM yyyy}", 
        width:100
    },
    {
        field: "dataChimpdv",
        title: "Data Chiusura Impegni PDV",
        format:"{0:dddd dd MMM yyyy}", 
        width: 100
    },
    {
        field: "dataChimpsede",
        title: "Data Chiusura Impegni Sede",
        format:"{0:dddd dd MMM yyyy}", 
        width: 100
    },

    {
        field: 'statoPubblicazioneERP',
        title: 'Stato pubblicazione ERP',
        attributes: { 'class': 'align-center' },
        width: 100,
        template: function (dataItem) {
            //var sezioneDescr = _.get(_.find(this._filters.dataSources.sezioniVolantinoCurrentPromo, 'id', dataItem.sezioneId), 'descrizione', '');
            var statoPubblicazioneERPId = _.get(dataItem, 'statoPubblicazioneERP', 1);
            var statoPubblicazioneERPCode = commonLookupData.getItemCodeById(constants.commonLookupDataNames.statiPubblicazione, statoPubblicazioneERPId);
            var statoPubblicazioneERPDescr = commonLookupData.getItemDescrById(constants.commonLookupDataNames.statiPubblicazione, statoPubblicazioneERPId);

            return '' +
                '<span class="ff-item ajax-loading" data-id-reparto="' + dataItem.repartoId + '"><img src="img/ajaxLoading2.gif" /></span> ';
        }.bind(this),
    },
];
```

I would like to add these widgets below each column.
Can you help me to understand how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with.  You will need to make use of a footer template(https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.footertemplate). In this template let's say you have 2 buttons.  You can use whatever you want and style it how you want.  What is important here are the events.

```
<button class="subtract-btn" data-column-id="Column1">&minus;</button>
<button class="add-btn" data-column-id="Column1">&plus;</button>
```

Now set up some JQuery to handle the events like so. Of course this assumes the date you are trying to change is bound to the column. In this case that date is called Column1

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#grid').on('click', '.subtract-btn', subtractDate);
    $('#grid').on('click', '.add-btn', addDate);
});

function subtractDate(e) {
    var columnId = $(this).data('columnId');
    var data = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data();
    var dataLen = data.length;
    var item, columnValue;

    for (var i = 0; i < dataLen; i++) {
        item = data[i];
        columnValue = item[columnId];
        columnValue.setDate(columnValue.getDate() - 1); //I prefer to use momentjs
        item.set(columnId, columnValue); //Forces UI update
    }
}

function addDate(e) {
    var columnId = $(this).data('columnId');
    var data = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data();
    var dataLen = data.length;
    var item, columnValue;

    for (var i = 0; i < dataLen; i++) {
        item = data[i];
        columnValue = item[columnId];
        columnValue.setDate(columnValue.getDate() + 1); //I prefer to use momentjs
        item.set(columnId, columnValue); //Forces UI update
    }
}
```